# Lipschitz homotopy groups

Tags: reference-request, gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry, heisenberg-groups

There is an extensive literature on Lipschitz homotopies of Lipschitz maps. But I haven't seen anything about Lipschitz homotopy groups. We have introduced this notion in an article that you can find

[here](http://www.ams.org/journals/ecgd/2014-18-08/S1088-4173-2014-00267-7/home.html).

> **Definition**. *Let $(X, x_0)$ be a pointed metric space. We define Lipschitz homotopy groups $\pi^{\rm Lip}_n(X, x_0)$ in the same way as
>   classical homotopy groups, with the exception that both the maps and
>   homotopies are required to be Lipschitz. We emphasize that we make no
>   restriction on the Lipschitz constants. In particular, we do not
>   require that the optimal Lipschitz constant for a homotopy between two
>   pointed maps $f, g : ([0, 1]^n, \partial[0, 1]^n) → (X, x_0)$,  be
>   comparable to that of the maps $f$ and $g$.*

This is an obvious definition, but difficult to use and perhaps this
 is why I could not find it anywhere. My question is:

> **Question.** Do you know if  this notion has been introduced before?

I just want to be able to
 give credit to those who used it before.

> **Motivation.** Note that in the case of smooth manifolds, Lipschitz homotopy groups are the same as classical homotopy groups, because
>   every homotopy can be smoothly approximated. However, for other spaces
>   this is not the case. For example for the van Koch curve $K$ that is
>   homeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^1$ so we have $\pi_1(K)=\mathbb{Z}$, but
>   Lipschitz mappings from $\mathbb{S}^1$ to $K$ are necessarily
>   constant. Well, this example is not interesting. In order to have
>   interesting examples we need spaces that are not smooth but have many
>   rectifiable curves and a particularly interesting examples are given
>   by the **Heisenberg groups**.

The closest notion I can think of is the notion of *Lipschitz $n$-connected spaces* studied and perhaps invented by Lang and  Schlichenmaier 
(
[link to MathSciNet](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=all&pg4=AUCN&pg5=TI&pg6=ALLF&pg7=JOUR&pg8=ET&review_format=html&s4=lang%2C%20u%2A&s5=&s6=&s7=&s8=All&sort=Newest&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq&r=12&mx-pid=2200122)).

Comment: The existence of smooth approximation (and relative smooth approximation) results, particularly those defined by convolution, lead me to expect that these agree with the standard homotopy groups. Intuitively they "fit between" smooth and continuous homotopy, which coincide.

Comment: @Mike Miller In the case of smooth manifolds there is no difference between classical and Lipschitz homotopy groups. The difference is when we work with metric spaces. For example in the case of the Heisenberg groups the classical homotopy groups are trivial, because the space is homeomorphic to the Euclidean space, but some of the Lipschitz homotopy groups are not trivial.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you for the point of clarification!

Comment: Why do you say you haven't seen anything? In your paper you're quoting papers involving "lipschitz homotopy groups" (by Wenger-Young).

Comment: The paper _Lipschitz homotopy groups of the Heisenberg groups_ by Wenger and Young was written after ours, but published before ours. In fact, in the paper they answered some of the questions from our paper.

Comment: Actually I remember discussing this notion with Wenger (and others), and this was at the time of the previous article https://arxiv.org/abs/1004.2907 (in the IHP semester in January-March 2011). Basically it became transparent that his result was related to the fact that the asymptotic cone of the group in consideration has a nontrivial Lipschitz $\pi_1$.