# Whitney's approximation theorem for Lipschitz manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, mg.metric-geometry, homotopy-theory, metric-spaces

In the smooth setting, Whitney's approximation theorem says the following: If $M,N$ are smooth manifolds and $f,g:M\to N$ are smooth functions that are continuously homotopic (ie there is a continuous homotopy $H:M\times [0,1]\to N$ between them) then they are also smoothly homotopic (ie there exists a smooth homotopy $\tilde{H}$ between them).

Does something similar hold for Lipschitz functions between Lipschitz manifolds? More precisely, **if $M,N$ are two Lipschitz manifolds and $f,g:M\to N$ are Lipschitz functions that are continuously homotopic, is it true that they are also Lipschitz homotopic (ie there exists a Lipschitz homotopy between them)?**

Comment: see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/295213/lipschitz-homotopy-groups. Apparently, Heisenberg group, which is contractible, has some nontrivial Lipschitz homotopy groups.

Comment: Thanks. But the Heisenberg group is a smooth manifold, right? So how does this reconcile with the comment (in the question you linked) that says that for smooth manifolds smooth and Lipschitz homotopy groups coincide?

Comment: Yes, Heisenberg group is a Lie group, hence a smooth manifold. Lipschitz homotopy groups depend on the metric, and in this case it is the  Carnot-Carateodory metric, see https://arxiv.org/pdf/1210.6943.pdf. There could be Lipschitz spheres that are smoothly fillable but not Lispschitz fillable.

Comment: I see. But I am afraid that my question remains open then, since in the example of the Heisenberg group the Lipschitz structure is not the one induced by the Lipschitz manifold structure...

Comment: Thanks, but Wikipedia seems to say that every PL manifold can be given a (unique) Lipschitz structure, not vice versa. If the vice versa were true, however, I agree that the result should follow.

Comment: The identity and the negation are two Lipschitz functions $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ that are homotopic, but not Lipschitz homotopic. . . . The Lipschitz condition has both small-scale and large-scale restrictions. Most people only really want one and should specify which. If you restrict to compact manifolds, it's just a small-scale condition, whereas this example is a coarse phenomenon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For compact Lipschitz manifolds this follows from the main result of the paper
by Liu, Luofei, Yu, Hanfu,
Liu, Ye
"[Converting uniform homotopies into Lipschitz homotopies via moduli of
continuity.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0166864120303205)" Topology Appl. 285 (2020)

But the above paper is surely an overkill. It gives quantitative bounds on the homotopy and qualitative result should be known much earlier.

I expect it's known that for a compact Lipschitz manifold $N$, for some Lipschitz embedding of $N$ into some $\mathbb R^n$ a small neighbourhood of $N$ Lipschitz retracts onto $N$. This would easily imply the result.

It's likely even true that $N$ is a Lipschitz ANR.

It's also clear that there is an appropriate version of this for noncompact manifolds too.

Edit: I found a reference to the fact that any Lipschitz manifold  is a Lipschitz ANR. This immediately follows from Theorem 5.1 in [this paper](http://www.acadsci.fi/mathematica/Vol03/vol03pp085-122.pdf).

Therefore what I said above works. It is enough to show that any two sufficiently $C^0$ close Lipschitz maps $f,g:M\to N$ are Lipschitz homotopic.
Embed $N$ by a Lipschitz map into a Euclidean space $\mathbb R^n$,  connect  $f$ to $g$ by straight line homotopy in $\mathbb R^n$ and then use Lipschitz neighborhood retraction to push this homotopy into $N$.

Comment: The link goes through your university library. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0166864120303205 is a better one.

Comment: thanks Igor, I should have checked.  It should be fixed now.

Comment: Thanks. The last paper in particular seems to be a very good reference for all that relates to Lipschitz manifolds.